# Unity freezes during while loop with timer or keybard input to break it

Tags: unity-game-engine, while-loop, freeze

I'm designing a psychology experiment. I need to wait for x number of seconds (WordDuration variable) or end loop early if a button was pressed. But unity freezes instead. How do I fix this? Maintaining timing accuracy is essential (preferred at the ms resolution),

```
       double StartTime = Time.realtimeSinceStartup;
        while (true)
        {
            double tt = Time.realtimeSinceStartup - StartTime;
            if (tt > WordDuration) break;
            if (Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.Space)) break; 

        }
```

Comment: correct, it will freeze because you have a loop  that just goes round and round and depending on where this code is, it will cause a freeze..  Chances are you want this in either a coroutine (which some people hate) or to use await if you're on the right version of unity

Answer (score 0):

While Loops are constant and do not stop until their condition is met, and this can cause the unity process to stop when it runs out of memory. To resolve this, place this at the end of the While Loops.

yield return null;

Comment: OK. The thing is that I need very accurate reaction time, preferably at t he 1 ms level. So, waiting every frame is problematic.

Comment: @OrenPoliva I got bad news for you then. The input is only updated every frame, so you're already playing with ±9ms (at 60fps). I wouldn't be too upset tho. You know the exact error and you can take it into account when making your statistic. Imagine having to estimate the interrupt delay for your physical key, the length of the interrupt routine, the delay until the kernel gives Unity the time of day, the time it takes to load the program, run the program, handle the kernel request to look up the system clock...